# ComboBox values Retrival and assign to Stored Procedure

Tags: c#

I have ComboBox and I fill it with a Dataset:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "post_code";
```

where `ds1` is dataset with one column post_code

It is sucessfuly showing data in ComboBox but when I am trying to save that ComboBox value in Table with:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Mt_Vacancy_mainPreference_insert",con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@post_name", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim();
```

it shows Error as Data.DataRowView. I also tried using SelectedValue.

Comment: Ok Friends, I got d answer   ComboBox1.ValueMember="Rowname";  //row name means db column name here "post_code"

Comment: Accept the answer by clicking on the green checkmark next to the answer that answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Assign the `ValueMember` of `comboBox1`.

`comboBox1.ValueMember = "YourValueField";`

then use `SelectedValue` of `comboBox1`

`string x = comboBox1.SelectedValue;`